# How to make a Customizer partial force full refresh instantly?

Tags: theme-customizer

I have a setting that basically needs the whole page to refresh. However, I still want to have a shortcut icon to its controller. If I do that, though, I need to implement a `render_callback` that reproduces the targeted element by the `selector`. I don't want that. I want a full page refresh.

Here's what I currently have (an example with `blogname` for simplicity):

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogname' )->transport = 'postMessage';
$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'blogname', array(
    'selector' => '.logo a',
    'render_callback' => function () {
        $wp_customize->requestFullRefresh();
    }
) );
```

This works, but not perfectly. When a change to the `blogname` setting occurs, first the `<a>` element flashes (tries to be rendered) and *then* the whole page refreshes.

### Questions

1. How do I skip directly to the full page refresh and not wait for the partial refresh?
2. Is there a better way to do this? Requesting a refresh in the *render* callback seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 3):

If you always want a page refresh, then all you have to do is simply remove this line:

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogname' )->transport = 'postMessage';
```

Or explicitly set it to `refresh`:

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogname' )->transport = 'refresh';
```

By doing this, selective refresh will never get invoked to refresh the partial, and it will skip straight to the full refresh.

Note it is preferable to return `false` in the `render_callback` to indicate you want to trigger a refresh. In your example, it is actually causing a fatal error because there is no such method. The same fallback behavior to do a full refresh is still happening when returning `false` or causing a fatal error, but in the latter case your error log is getting filled up.

In short, your example can be modified to:

```
$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'blogname', array(
    'selector' => '.logo a',
    'render_callback' => '__return_false',
) );
```